# Gradle: how to get task name from copySpec?

Tags: gradle

Gradle: how to get task name from copySpec?
e.g.,

```
def myCopySpec = {
   
    def patterns = project.getProperty("${task.name}_patterns")
    filesMatching(patterns) {
        ....
    }
}

task myTask(type: Copy) {

   with myCopySpec
}

task myTask2(type: Copy) {

   with myCopySpec
}

task myTask3(type: Copy) {

   with myCopySpec
}
```